# Retrieve Row from MYSQL Table and Echo content - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, echo, record, url-parameters

I cannot seem to be able to echo anything from my table. The connection is fine.

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$id=$_GET['version'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT url, logo FROM versions WHERE version = ".$id);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo $row['url'];


?>
```

version, url and logo are attributes in table called versions.
the URL parameter is version. The test URL is

```
http://localhost/view?version="a"
```

Echo is not giving out anything.

Please, help.

Comment: what is the data type of version ?

Comment: the data type is text

Comment: Hi cody, try it like this `var_dump($row)`

Answer (score 3):

this should be like this:

```
   http://localhost/view?version=a
```

and your code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['version']);
$res = mysql_query("SELECT url, logo FROM versions WHERE version = '$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

echo $row['url'];


?>
```

I added mysql_real_escape_string to sanitize $_GET for protection from sql injection, and surrounded $id with `'` in the query because it is a string, not an integer.

NB: you should stop using mysql_ because these functions are deprecated, start using mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the query as

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT url, logo FROM versions WHERE version = '".$id."'");
```

Also your code is very insecure !! You need to sanitize the $_GET['version'] using mysql_real_escape_string().

Better use mysqli_* or PDO